# RHEL Apache Test Page shown on navigation to EC2 IP address

Tags: centos, rhel, apache-httpd, amazon-ec2

I have a `Django` app that runs on `8080`, `apachectl configtest` shows no errors and `python manage.py runserver` runs it without any errors. However the regardless of whether the app is running or not, the RHEL apache test page shows up when I navigate to my EC2 instance.

Is this a permissions issue?

`httpd -v` output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
Server built:   May 28 2018 16:19:32
```

Here is the `httpd.conf` ([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/Q2bbj8jS))

Here is the `vhosts.conf` ([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/K5WL6rsf))

Comment: How are you navigating to the EC2 instance? Via an IP address? A hostname? Navigating by IP address will serve files from `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Aha! So you are saying that I need to put the IP address instead of the VHOSTS and/or apache conf file?

Comment: Do you have a hostname associated with the server? The vhosts.conf file is configured for `product.med.organization.com` and `suite.med.organization.com`. So if that hostname works for your server then Apache will use the virtual host configuration starting on line 26 and 85 of the vhosts.conf.

Comment: No not yet. These hostnames need to be moved at the DNS level to the new IP addresses from their older IP addresses (on an older server). But in the meantime could I replace those with the IP addresses for testing purposes?

Comment: Do you have SSL setup? Right now the http server is set to automatically redirect traffic to the SSL servers at `product.med.organization.com` and `suite.med.organization.com`. So if you don't have SSL, you'll need to change the configuration in the vhosts.conf file on lines 5-15.

Comment: Yes, here is the link: https://pastebin.com/XMs3SLXh

Answer (score 0):

You can run the virtual hosts off IP address instead of host names.

So, on line 26 of your vhosts.conf file it should read:

`<VirtualHost <EXTERNAL IP>:443>`

Where  is the IP address of your server.